# How to remove stylush from Vuetify plugin and add Vuetify SCSS in Vue Js project

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, vue-cli-3

I installed [vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/quick-start) plugin in my vuejs project. i am using vue cli 3. i selected vuetify recommended option to install. but i am already using SCSS in my project. vuetify added stylush.

How can i remove stylush and use [vuetify SCSS](https://github.com/nmsmith22389/vuetify-scss) with best practice or do i need to start over from uninstalling vuetify and remove added files and code?

Comment: Just remove the line which includes css/styl? I presume it's located in `vuetify.js`?